# Two Tiles and One Application

Tags: sapui5

We have this scenario in which we would like to use the same ui5 application for 2 different Launchpad tiles. When user clicks on first tile all the data should be displayed in Smart table but when user clicks on second tile same table will be used but before displaying the content some filter will be applied and less data will be shown.

I am thinking of get the tile ID and according to the tile , I will apply the filter. How it can be achieved ?

Regards,
MS

Answer (score 0):

[Multiple tile](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview)

once you have added tile use press event to call function and provide event as parameter to that function.Using below line You can get title OR use _getTileIndex() and accordingly you can apply filter

sap.ui.getCore().byId(oEvent.getParameters().id).getTitle()

Comment: Thanks for Reply Suryabhan. But how in my application , I will get the ID of the tile from Fioro Launch Pad. If It was a normal tile container , I would have get it with press event.

Comment: You can get Id by using press event. According to Your scenario how you want to retrieve id. Please provide some more information regarding your difficulties you are facing to fetch id.